# ‘class QApplication’ has no member named ‘setMainWidget’

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm attempting to compile a "Hello World!" application using Qt but on compilation I'm getting the following error: `‘class QApplication’ has no member named ‘setMainWidget’` and I'm not sure why, my source file looks like:

```
/****************************************************************
**
** Qt tutorial 1
**
****************************************************************/

#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    QPushButton hello( "Hello world!", 0 );
    hello.resize( 100, 30 );

    a.setMainWidget( &hello );
    hello.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

and I created the Makefile with `cmake` using following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(hello_world)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# Create code from a list of Qt designer ui files
#set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

# Populate a CMake variable with the sources
set(hello_world_SRCS
            main.cpp
            )
# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(hello_world WIN32 ${hello_world_SRCS})
# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5
target_link_libraries(hello_world Qt5::Widgets)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `QT5` but `setMainWidget` was as obsolete already in `QT4`. In QT5 there is no this method. You can just remove this line from the code. And everything will work.

Comment: @rafix07 Oh wow, great! Thank you, you can move the comment to an answer and I will accept! Thanks! :)

Comment: Just remove line: `a.setMainWidget( &hello );`